# Viewport tag not working on Chrome

Tags: html, responsive-design, viewport

I'm using the device metrics override in Chrome to test a responsive website for smaller resolutions (320x480 in this case).

My viewport meta tag is not making any effect on the page in this case. The logo will appear tiny, and I it's completely unreadable. More or less, I'd say I'm seeing everything in a .5 scale.

Here's the head of my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mediaqueries.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" / >
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <style>
    .wrapper {min-width: 960px; padding: 0 10px;}
    .hovertext {background: #ccc;}
    </style>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.0.6-development-only.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

This does work on other people's sites.... I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this in place of your meta tag. Good luck.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

Comment: That just helped me out of a sticky situation. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure you use comma's and not semicolons in `content`. Most browsers don't bother, but Chrome does.

Comment: +1 for you. but PLEASE, correct the typo and use 'coma' instead of semicolons  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />`