# Webview Displays the Web Page Small

Tags: android, html, webview

We developed an app with WebView.  I thought I got everything to display to full device width until we tested it in a Nexus 5 running KitKat.  At first I couldn't get the page to shrink on any device and fit without scrolling until I implemented the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=400px">
```

Target-density is the only thing that had an effect on changing the display size that I could find.  And it worked... until Nexus 5 with KitKat.  When displayed in the Nexus 5 it does the opposite now, it shrinks and I can't figure out how to display it to full width.  I started looking again and found:

> Viewport target-densitydpi no longer supported
>
> Previously, WebView supported a viewport property called
>   target-densitydpi to help web pages specify their intended screen
>
> density. This property is no longer supported and you should migrate
>   to using standard solutions with images and CSS as discussed in
>   Pixel-Perfect UI in the WebView.
>
> Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html

When I use this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

It displays too big again with scrolling bars and all the other devices would do the same thing.

I've found solutions (can't remember them anymore) that would work with Chrome and other browsers but not with WebView.  Webview seems quite strict.

Any ideas how this can be remedied?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add viewport meta tag in [this manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365750/viewport-tag-not-working-on-chrome/15395284#15395284). Hope it works for you in all the browsers.

Comment: unfortunately, I tested it with Galaxy Nexus android 4.3 and that doesn't work anymore, it's too thin, doesn't fill in the width. I didn't try it with KitKat device yet.