# Setting the minimum zoom amount for viewing an html page in browser

Tags: html, css, web

I've tried adding

```
@viewport {
/* Keyword value */
min-zoom: auto;

/* <number> values */
min-zoom: 0.8;
width: device-width;

}
```

and

```
body {
     width: 1500 px;
}
```

To my css document

And adding the meta tag to my html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.00, maximum-scale=2.00, minimum-scale=0.80">
```

And all of it seems to do nothing. The webpage can still zoom in and out just as it did before.

Is there anything else I need to add other than these things?

I'm using the firefox browser

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51667527/is-there-a-way-to-specify-minimum-and-maximum-zoom-level-for-a-browser
Does that answer your question?

Comment: @FelDev No, that meta tag is in my question

Comment: @Jacob: in which browsers? `min-zoom` has no support over all browsers (eg. safari).

Comment: @panther Well I'm using firefox. I'd like a way to set the minimum zoom over all the popular browsers, it doesn't have to be this way.